# Using non-ASCII characters as variable names in Python 2

Tags: python, ascii, python-2.x

The following code returns “Error: Invalid Syntax” when reaching the third line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print “åäö”
ÅÄÖ = 4
```

The print statement works fine despite holding non-ASCII characters. The problem seems to be when the non-ASCII characters are used as variable names. Doing this in Python 3 works perfectly fine, and I’ve understood that this is because Python 3 and 2 treat strings differently, but I need to use Python 2 for various reasons.

Being able to write the letters åäö in Python 2.7 would be extremely valuable to me, partly because I am fairly new to programming in Python and strongly prefer naming my variables and functions in Swedish as it makes them much easier to separate from Pythons in-built functions.

Comment: Not supported. Get used to it. It's not fundamentally that different from getting used to not being able to put spaces, `.`, `-`, or other punctuation in your variable names.

Comment: Probably worth the effort to move to Python 3 - if you're used to Swedish, I expect you'd be working with non-ASCII strings as data fairly frequently, and Python 2 will be a constant low-level annoyance at minimum in that case. What is keeping you on 2?

Comment: @David Heyman Well, I am trying to make a pygame game that i've made available to android, and everything I've googled suggests that you either have to use Kivy or python 2.7 in order to do that. Something tells me that this is a terrible idea and that I should just go to java instead, but many sources I've looked at claim that it's entierly possible to make android apps with python.

Comment: @gelbrekt Ah. I've got no experience there. But based on a quick search - I think Kivy works in Python 3. Or you could try Lua, perhaps - that's much closer to Python than Java is, and the LÖVE engine is compatible with pretty much everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this. The language syntax specification simply doesn't allow it for Python 2.x:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

As you already discovered this was changed for Python 3 where the syntax allows certain kinds of non-ascii characters to occur in identifiers

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

(Note that identifiers are something else entirely as string literals!)